Clarification on a GEE model including time-varying covariates
I was wondering if GEE method can work with time varying covariates? I have a longitudinal study which include time dependent covariates and I am not sure wether I can still use GEE model or not
Based on the following publication https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/3252-2015.pdf
it seems that GEE method is not assured to have consistent estimators when using time-dependent covariates, also in the following link https://mbounthavong.com/blog/tag/time-varying+covariates, it is mentioned that 'Conventional methods to perform longitudinal data analysis such as linear mixed effects models and generalized estimating equations models are capable of handling time-varying covariates. However, in the case of a time-varying elements, the probability of treatment exposure is invariably different across time, which requires application of time-varying weights on the unit of analysis'`*
